# What is the difference between platform and tool?

Tags: comparison, compare, definition

The question is telling everything

Reason why I ask:

> Maven is more of a platform than a
>   tool, while you could consider Maven
>   an alternative to Ant, you are
>   comparing apples to oranges. "Maven"
>   includes more than just a build tool.

What the heck does this mean?

Comment: voted to close for this reason "It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument." .. should I make it community wiki?

Comment: The question is not telling everything, Gandalf the Contextless.

Comment: An analogy: Middle Earth would be a platform and a Hobbit a tool!

Comment: It's like "emacs is more of a platform than an editor." Of course, some of us would rather have an editor.

Comment: yes, why the unnecessary complexity then?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Although I know everything there is to know about hobbits and Middle Earth your analogy doesn't make any sense .. but its kinda funny .. to me that is ..

Comment: @Gandalf StormCrow: Sorry about that, it was meant as humour.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat point taken

Answer (score 1):

Different tools make apps for the same platform ... The quotation you brought up just claim that Maven does more than Ant so that it's not fair to compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

You build "things" on top of a *platform*. You build those "things" with *tools*.

To use an analogy, think of a city as a platform. The city (platform) provides basic services such as:

- Power
- Communications channels
- Sewage lines
- Streets
- Land/lots to build on
- Etc.

You can build all kinds of "things" within a city - e.g. retail stores, office buildings, homes, movie theaters, etc. These "things" are all built using a wide variety of tools - e.g. hammers, saws, power drills, cranes, etc.

What all of these "things" have in common is that many/most of them make use of the various services provided by the city (platform). This allows you to build those "things" much more quickly and efficiently since you don't have to re-invent these services for each and every "thing" that you build.

It's also possible, due to economies of scale, that the services will be cheaper when they're provided as part of a platform vs. creating them for each use case. For example, you wouldn't want to create an electrical power plant for each home that you build.

In some cases, the "things" that get built can become part of the overall platform. For example, building a new electrical substation at the edge of a city can allow for new things to be built with easier, more efficient access to electricity increasing the overall capabilities of the platform.